# Kendo MVC: Adding Edit, Delete Buttons to Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Assuming I have the below table:

```
    @Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Staff").Columns(x =>
    {
        x.Bound(y => y.StaffId);
        x.Bound(y => y.FirstName);
        x.Bound(y => y.LastName);
        x.Bound(y => y.Email);
        x.Bound(y => y.Phone);
        x.Command(y => y.Custom("Edit").Action("edit", "controller", new { id = ????? }));

    }).Sortable().Scrollable().Pageable(x=> x.PageSizes(true)).Filterable()
```

How can I pass the primary key value (StaffId in this case) associated to the row to the object route values similar to the way it is done by Visual Studio auto-scaffold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the grid over and over, I could finally solve the problem. Here you go:

```
x.Bound(y => y.Title).Template(y=> "<a href=\""+y.Title+"\">Click Me</a>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you can pass ID using Command.Custom the way you are attempting right now.

If you prefer this way, you can define a JS method and fetch selected row in that and perform an AJAX operation to manipulate the data.

So in your case you can instead define command as:

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("editRow"));
```

and in script tag, you can define method that read and send data to server:

```
    function editRow(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        var searchId = dataItem.Id;
        var searchName = dataItem.Name;

        var model = { searchId: searchId };
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BindLeftMenu")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: JSON.stringify(model)
            })
            .success(function (resultMenu) { 
                $("#driversummaryarea").show();
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                $("div.overlay").hide();
            });            
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Now there are 2 other ways you can modify grid data:

1. Use default commands e.g. Edit(). A demo is shown [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline). Simple and easy but limiting i.e. less control from JS.
2. Use ClientTemplate - Very powerful as offers full control over display and capturing data in JS.

For example with ClientTemplate you can define a grid like below. Notice how we are passing model Id parameter in ClientTemplate as raw html.

Once you define ClientTemplate, you can define the JS functions fnEditUser as shown above and perform operation on grid data.

**HTML**

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Eda.RDBI.Web.Models.OrganizationUserViewModel>()
              .Name("organizationUserViewModelGrid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Filterable(true).Title("Name").Groupable(false).ClientTemplate("<a class='lnkEditUser' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='fnEditUser(#=Id#)' > #=FirstName# </a>").Width(200);

                  columns.Bound(p => p.EMail).Width(200);

                  columns.Bound(p => p.Role)
                      .ClientTemplate("<span>#=Role#</span> <span>#=IsDriverSearchAllowed ? ' (DS)' : ''#</span>");

                  columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Title("Active")
                      .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  #=IsActive ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' onclick='return false'/>");

                  columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Title(string.Empty).ClientTemplate("<a class='btn btn-default' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='fnDeleteUser(#=Id#)'>Delete</a>").Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
              })
              .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
              .Scrollable()
              .Filterable()
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .PageSize(50)
                  .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                  .Read(read => read.Action("GetUsersForOrganization", "OrganizationUser"))
              )
              .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
              )
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. I'm not interested in any javascript code that's why I only mentioned Razor helper. I don't understand Java Script at all. I only and only know ASP.NET and C#. No JQuery and JS knowdelge. Sorry to say but I hate them :D

Comment: What about #1? It is purely server side operation.

Comment: No, the problem with this grid is that it auto binds everything and doesn't let me normally build it in a foreach loop like civilized person :D. I don't want it to auto-bind. The sad thing I am forced to use it else I'd make my own table. so I have to pass the Id to the edit button as I mentioned. No Ajax no JS. This only seems possible through writing an extension method, but I can't figure where the current index of the model is kept in the Grid view.

Comment: Java Script is dirty and unorganized and messy, the worst thing is that the Visual Studio Intellisense hardly and partially supports it. I'm not a front-end guy so I'm not even interested in looking at JS codes. Other guys may love it, but not me.

Comment: Fine, not using JS is your choice. But I am not sure why you say "I don't want it to auto-bind." Any particular reason? From your code and description it seems like you are building a simple grid with a button that let user edit a row. What extra functionality you want to achieve for which you can not USE #1 i.e. default edit command (no JS).

Comment: The reason is that it restricts my maneuver around the table, It makes it rigid so I can't customize it. A foreach loop would be event faster in this case, because I'm sure the binding that is designed by telerik uses terribly heavy reflections slowing down the whole thing.

Comment: O I see. For customization and flexibility I am afraid you will have to use JS. But it is a good question. Not a big fan of Kendo (had struggled a lot with it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90586/discussion-between-sbirthare-and-arrrr).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. If you're not doing any AJAX, you might be able to just move the anchor into Template and not use ClientTemplate. I'm using bootstrap buttons, but you could replace that code with your own styles or the kendo styles.

This is the code that inserts your id: **#= Id #** - it should be a field from your Model. See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Staff").Columns(x =>
{
    x.Bound(y => y.StaffId);
    x.Bound(y => y.FirstName);
    x.Bound(y => y.LastName);
    x.Bound(y => y.Email);
    x.Bound(y => y.Phone);
    x.Template(@<text></text>).Title(string.Empty).Width(40)
     .ClientTemplate(@"<a href='" + Url.Action("Edit") + "?id=#= Id #' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' title='Modify this'>Edit</a>");
}).Sortable().Scrollable().Pageable(x=> x.PageSizes(true)).Filterable()
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it doesn't work, I can't figure out, I know that I have to change the `Id` to the actual property name, but the problem is that nothing actually is added to the table!

Comment: It should work. Start with some static text just to see the template column: x.Template(@<text>Server</text>).ClientTemplate(@"<text>Ajax</text>");

Comment: Then show your id: x.Template(@<text>#= Id #</text>).ClientTemplate(@"<text>#= Id #</text>");

Comment: `#= StaffId#` or `#= Id #` results in the exact same text as `#= StaffId#`. It is not working.

Comment: Did it show the simple static text? If not, see if there are any errors in browser console.

Comment: No, it only shows that syntax "#= {id} #" exactly as it is in the links. By the way, I have never seen anything like that before, is it something specific to telerik controls?

Comment: The only possible way to do it is to hardcode the buttons in the model which I had no choice but do it. A very bad move, but I wrote a method which mimics the functionality of ActionLink extensions to some level. Telerik just BLINDLY converted their UI to helpers, they did not considered anything when developing those helpers. I'd give them 0 out of 10 for their MVC components. DevExpress, and SyncFusion are way better than Kendo. Though as using Kendo is a requirement for this project I had no other option. Buying Kendo is totally a waste of money just in case they see this comment here!

Comment: That's not the only way to do it. If you refuse to work with javascript or jquery you will definitely be limited since these tools are all based in html and javascript (as is razor). That said, there are mechanism like templates with hash tag helpers to bridge the gap. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview I would build up - first get the new column added with the template, but WITHOUT the hash tag syntax then add that. Chrome Developer tools are great for identifying issues.

Comment: That hash tag does not work at all, I tried everything! even all browsers. By the way, what part of Razor is based on JS? Razor is a view engine that is not based on JS, but renders your C# code to HTML (Not JS). It uses Unobtrusive JS Scripts which means no JS will be generated!!

Comment: Yes, I was referring to unobtrusive validation which reads the tags to execute javascript. Not interested in a fight dude. I only come in here to get help on issues and provide it when I can. You are obviously frustrated by having to use a tool you don't want, but there are a lot of us out here making it work.

Comment: The grid renders exactly like `<tr><td>001</td><td>Jack</td></tr>` so I've been wondering how possibly could even telerik claim that hash tag would work! The grid does not add any attribute to the generated html. So it is very logical from my perspective that the hash tag cannot work. In order to do it, that `id` must be either rendered in server side which means hardcoding the additional component to model (terrible idea but no choice), or forcing the Grid to add some trackable unique value to an attribute in the rows and cells. Then yes JavaScript would be efficient.

Comment: Steve: Please see my answer, your answer gave me some idea though I appreciate it, but just see how I solved it. It wasn't a fight it was a discussion, and this discussion ignited the actual solution :D