# How could I do a custom column in Kendo grid, so it redirects to a action in a controller

Tags: html, asp.net-core, kendo-grid

I have a grid in which the last column has to be a button that redirects to a action in my controller.

I have to change a page to display data in a Kendo grid in stead of in a table.

The problem that I have is how can I pass the id of the current item to the action.

Here is the old table

```
<table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                            </td>
                            <!--<td>
                                Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                            </td>-->
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Edit</a>  |
                                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>
```

And here is the updated one

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EndoIS.Models.UserViewModel>()
            .Name("Videos")
            .Columns(columns => {
                columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
            })
            .Pageable(pager => pager
                .Messages(messages => messages.Display("{0} - {1} od {2} vrstic"))
                .Messages(messages => messages.ItemsPerPage("rows per page"))
                .Messages(messages => messages.Empty("No rows"))
                )
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))
            .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                 .Ajax()
                 .ServerOperation(false)
                 .Read(read => read.Action("List", "UserAdmin"))
            )
)
```

Now how can I add the last column from the old table into this grid so it would open the same page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kendo MVC: Adding Edit, Delete Buttons to Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773431/kendo-mvc-adding-edit-delete-buttons-to-grid)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easy way to access the current model with `#= Id #` so I did it like this

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Email).ClientHeaderTemplate("Edit").ClientTemplate(@"<a href='" + Url.Action("Edit") + "/#= Id #' class='btn btn-info btn-xs'>Edit</a>").Width(100);
```

There is probably a better way to do this but I did it like this and it works